# Installing Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 alongside Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, 18.04, windows-10

How can I install Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 alongside Windows 10 into separate  partitions I've pre-made on a drive?

I do not seem to have the option when stepping through the installation. The partitions that I have set up can install fine using the desktop version of Ubuntu, but not the server version. There doesn't appear to be a "something else" or "other" option when setting up partitions with Ubuntu Server.

Output of "fdisk -l":

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D79107CC-1431-41E2-9BFA-DD281BDA96A8

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    2099199   2097152     1G EFI System
/dev/sda2    2099200  102098943  99999744  47.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  102098944  421529599 319430656 152.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  421529600  422551551   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  422551552  422756351    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda6  422756352  422789119     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda7  422789120 1000214527 577425408 275.3G Microsoft basic data
```

Currently, `/dev/sda2` is `/` and `dev/sda3` is `/home`, and `swap` is on a separate hard drive. I do not see any of these partitions in any of the options I have selected during the Ubuntu Server installation, maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu Server installation media and installer **do not have** a side-by-side installation feature.  That is a Desktop-installer-only feature at the moment.

If you intend to do a 'side by side' installation with Ubuntu Server's installation media, you'll have to do the 'side by side' stuff manually.

Adjust your partitions manually, resizing and/or creating the partitions through a separate mechanism such as Windows or another Ubuntu ISO (boot to Ubuntu Desktop and use `gparted`), and then do a custom partitioning scheme when you are presented with the "Use whole disk", "Use whole disk and LVM", "Something else", etc. partitioning step, and specify the partition(s) and mountpoints to utilize manually.

Alternatively, install the Desktop version of Ubuntu, and then just install server packages inside of it.  Under the hood, Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop are both "Ubuntu" and can both run server packages without issue, the difference is that Ubuntu Server is 'headless' and has no GUI overhead to worry about, as well as a different 'default' packageset.  But you can still use a Desktop install for server packages nonetheless.